# Transaction not rolled back in Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions, spring-test

Transaction does not get rolled back on the SpringBoot Test case.

The entries are inserted in the database when the test is run.

I tried using the @Transactional annotation above the test method, but the rollback doesn't work.

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void testNumber() {
    given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body("{   \n" +
            "    \"pattern\":\"[A-Za-z0-9]",\n" +
            "    \"data\":{\n" +
            "          \"name\": \"Cina\"\n" +

            "     }\n" +
            "}").expect().statusCode(200).when().post("/testservice/").andReturn();
}
```

Does this happen because autocommit is by default set to true in spring boot.

I am using JpaTransactionManager as the PlatformTransactionManager. Does this manager set the autocommit to true..

Any suggestions are helpful.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse they are committed. You are running an integration test, the system is started and a url is called. This happens in a separate proces and not as part of your testcase. It is like running the application nd calling a url, nothing to rollback.

Comment: @Denium, Thanks for the quick reply ..  How can I avoid the commit in this scenario .. Pls suggest ..

Comment: You cannot as you are basically calling a deployed application...